# How can I prevent both vertical and horizontal stretching of contained text while resizing text-based objects in Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, draw

I want to be able to scale text-based objects (for example with classes and subclasses of IText, Textbox) without stretching the text inside of the object. The interaction of scaling and moving is on user-side (UI), not programmatically (I am working on a drawing editor).

[image]

**The behaviour I am looking for is similar to the one in the sticky notes apps: You can scale the paper but this action does not scale your text too.**

I have already checked this, but this is only for horizontal prevention: [Fabric.js How to resize IText horizontally without stretching the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026324/fabric-js-how-to-resize-itext-horizontally-without-stretching-the-text)

This is neither what I want/mean: [Fabric.js : How to set a custom size to Text or IText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187154/fabric-js-how-to-set-a-custom-size-to-text-or-itext)

I know that a scaling factor different than 1 implies the stretching of the inner text, and that by changing the `width` and `height` I can resize the object while keeping the text unscaled, so I tried updating these during scaling using events listeners.

I tried many combinations of the IText,Textbox with some scaling events, like this one:

```
fbtext.on('scaling', function() {
                      this.set({
                        width : this.width  * this.scaleX,
                        height: this.height * this.scaleY,
                        scaleX: 1,
                        scaleY: 1,
                      });
                    });
```

I also tried this with Textbox:

```
fbtext.on('scaling', function() {
                      this.set({
                        height: this.height * this.scaleY,
                      });
                    });
```

But nothing worked so far. I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mycanvas');

let textbox = new fabric.Textbox("Sample text", {
   left: 100,
   top: 100
});

let lastHeight;

const updateTextSize = () => { 

  const controlPoint = textbox.__corner;

  //mr and ml are the only controlPoints that dont modify textbox height
  if( controlPoint && controlPoint != "mr" && controlPoint != "ml"){
     lastHeight =  textbox.height * textbox.scaleY;   
  }

  textbox.set({  
    height: lastHeight || textbox.height,
  scaleY:1    
  });
  
  canvas.renderAll();
};
  
 
textbox.on('scaling', updateTextSize );
textbox.on('editing:entered', updateTextSize);
canvas.on('text:changed', updateTextSize);
  
canvas.add(textbox);
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.3.2/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Here is a code sample that will let you modify the "sticky note size" without streching out the text

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: @Ivan, Any clue how to do this for IText? That would be of great help. 
thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @Ivan, hi! Is there a way to enable resizing the box both horizontally and vertically at the same time? Currently with this solution, I am able to do both, but not at the same time. Also when I resize horizontally, any vertical stretch jumps back to the heigh of the content.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ivan, your solution is working for me, with a small glitch.
When increasing the size of the text box using corners the text is getting stretched and compressed. I haven't found the solution of this yet and have currently implemented a workaround to hide all the corner scaling points.

```
box.setControlsVisibility({
bl: false,
br: false,
tl: false,
tr: false
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bkgvewh6/

Just to add I am posting this as an answer and not as a comment to your answer as I don't have stack overflow reputation to do so.